# Setting up a Native Library on JMonkey IDE

Tags: java, jmonkeyengine, leap-motion

How to set a Native Library (*.dll) location of a jar file in JMonkey IDE?

I'm trying to connect Leap Motion with JMonkey engine. Therefore I need to put LeapJava.jar in build path. As the native library is not set,(coz I don't know how to) following error occurs when executing.

> Native code library failed to load.
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no LeapJava in java.library.path

Comment: If the JMonkey IDE is actually Eclipse, the instructions here should work: https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/java/devguide/Project_Setup.html#eclipse

Comment: @CharlesWard your comment lead me to the correct way. JMonkey built in top of NetBeans. So I should google for NetBeans rather than saying exactly JMonkey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jMonkeyEngine SDK is built in top of the NetBeans Platform, and is identical to the NetBeans IDE for Java. 
So setting up the Native Library location of a jar file is same as the NetBeans.

Charles Ward comment lead me to the solution.